# PHP/MySql - DateTime detecting if values was assigned?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to make an if statement that only runs if the datetime value is NOT null `(0000-00-00 00:00:00)`

I have passed the value via a query into a variable but how do i determine if it equals `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "' "; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
  $money = $row['money'];
  $bank_money = $row['bank_money'];
  $ap = $row['ap'];
  $exp = $row['exp']; 
  $last_ap_update = $row['last_ap_update'];
} 

if ($last_ap_update != ){ //Can i verify its NULL-ness here so i can run this if stament or run else?
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're fetching one row at maximum. You don't need a while-loop for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not directly compare it :

```
if ($last_ap_update != "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
{
      //do whatever.
}
```

Comment: ohhhh i didnt know. I though datetime values couldn't be compared with strings. Are datetime values just formatted strings?

Answer (score 1):

You store it into a variable so you can use it as a string

```
if ($last_ap_update != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($last_ap_update != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
    [process]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$last_ap_update != strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00")`

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the comparison to your sql statement?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "' AND  last_ap_update > 0";
```

Yes, you can use `> 0` but you can also use `<> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` if you prefer that.